# capture audio data from sound card windows xp

Tags: c#, .net, audio-streaming, audio-recording, naudio

My requirement is to capture whatever (audio)is playing on client machine and send it to server as live streaming. On windows 7 i am banging my head on WASAPI Loopback for this purpose. But that is not supported in windows XP. Do anyone has idea how it can be done in Windows Xp?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DirectX.

Take look at this:
[capturing sound and more with Managed DirectX (MDX) 1.1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31356/C-MP3-Sound-Capturing-Recording-Component)

Comment: unfortunately this will only capture whatever inputs the soundcard offers, and not whatever audio is playing on the system.

Comment: "this will only capture whatever inputs the soundcard offers"              Does that mean it will capture raw data instead of only sound data? If yes then is there any other way to get audio data from sound card programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP does not provide built-in support for loopback capture. Your can only do it if your soundcard has a "what you hear" option that can be selected for recording. If not, then you would need to use a specially created sound card driver that allows you to intercept the audio being sent to it, and passes it on to your real soundcard. There are a few commercial products that do this (such as [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm))

Comment: I never saw sound card that doesnt have "what you hear" loopback.